# Kubernetes fails to do do garbage collection on images

Tags: docker, kubernetes

For quiet some time every once in a while I get an alert, that the disk of one of my Kubernetes cluster nodes is filling up. I pretty quickly found out, that it were the Docker images. As I did not have time to deeper analyze the issue, I just used `docker system prune` to get rid of everything not running (yeah, I know this is highly discouraged).

Now I started to look into this issue and it seems, that the garbage collector has issues with the images:

```bash
max@nb [~]
-> % k get events -owide
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON          OBJECT          SUBOBJECT   SOURCE                MESSAGE                                                             FIRST SEEN   COUNT   NAME
3m15s       Warning   ImageGCFailed   node/cluster00              kubelet, cluster00    failed to get imageFs info: non-existent label "docker-images"      69d          20073   cluster00.16fa70fb01b64a69
4m15s       Warning   ImageGCFailed   node/cluster02              kubelet, cluster02    failed to get imageFs info: non-existent label "docker-images"      69d          20085   cluster02.16fa6da5f5b30c31
54s         Warning   ImageGCFailed   node/cluster04              kubelet, cluster04    failed to get imageFs info: non-existent label "docker-images"      69d          20082   cluster04.16fa6ea64df694c5
3m57s       Warning   ImageGCFailed   node/cluster05              kubelet, cluster05    failed to get imageFs info: non-existent label "docker-images"      69d          20087   cluster05.16fa6d1f167fe7f4
48s         Warning   ImageGCFailed   node/cluster06              kubelet, cluster06    failed to get imageFs info: non-existent label "docker-images"      69d          20077   cluster06.16fa700540142542
2m21s       Warning   ImageGCFailed   node/cluster11              kubelet, cluster11    failed to get imageFs info: non-existent label "docker-images"      69d          20074   cluster11.16fa70c17857fef8
max@nb [~]
-> %
```

I have two other nodes in the cluster, that are newer than the others and do not seem to have the same issue:

```bash
max@nb [~]
-> % kubectl get nodes
NAME        STATUS   ROLES                  AGE      VERSION
cluster00   Ready    control-plane,master   4y107d   v1.23.8
cluster02   Ready    <none>                 2y270d   v1.23.8
cluster04   Ready    <none>                 3y267d   v1.23.8
cluster05   Ready    <none>                 4y107d   v1.23.8
cluster06   Ready    <none>                 3y171d   v1.23.8
cluster11   Ready    <none>                 592d     v1.23.8
cluster12   Ready    <none>                 139d     v1.23.8
cluster13   Ready    <none>                 139d     v1.23.8
max@nb [~]
-> %
```

The cluster was initially setup more than four years ago manually with `kubeadm`. If I remember correctly, the version was 1.9.6 back then. And I updated it from there up to 1.23.8 right now. When the last two nodes (the working ones) were added, the cluster was on 1.19.8.

It is very much possible, that I forgot some configuration change in any of the upgrades. 69 days ago (the time the first appeared as of `get events`) I did the upgrade from 1.19.8 to 1.23.8 (and all versions in-between, of course). Could be, that the issue started then. Could also be, that the upgrade *cleared* the events log. Not sure if the issue was already there before, to be honest.

Has anyone any idea where I could start looking for the reason of this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I fixed the issue.

It seems it comes up, when the `kubelet` service starts before the `docker` service is up and running. So I added the directive `After=docker.service` to the `[Unit]` block of the `kubelet` service and restarted it. The issue seems to be gone now.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix by below works for me:

```
docker system prune
systemctl stop kubelet
systemctl stop docker
systemctl start docker
systemctl start kubelet
```

Comment: Yep, this should work as long as the node is not restarted. Adding the `After` directive to the systemd service makes sure, that the services are always started in the correct order.